# How can I adjust this query to add conditionals from other columns? Formula / sample sheet included

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TjkR3TEg_eSei-25zUm8yRimftQ6ocRKQNEfrN-9Ogc/edit?usp=sharing

^ Sample sheet with my current formula, sample data, and description of the problem/current situation.

The current formula calculates the average of the last 10 appearances (going from the bottom of the sheet upwards) of columns C or D when "New York" (cell K1) is in columns B or C.
If New York appears in column B then it uses the value in column D, and if New York appears in column C it uses the value in column E.

The improvement I want to make is that it only uses the values (within those last 10 appearances of "New York" / cell K1) based on conditionals of columns G/F. In this case, let's say >10 as the conditional.

When "New York" is in columns B/C, for the last 10 appearances, it should bring the value in D into the equation if the value in F is >10 (and New York is in column B), and it should bring E into the equation if the value in G >10 (and New York is in column C).

Any ideas?

Comment: Done, just edited with a better description. Sorry, assumed the info in the sheet was more than enough.

Comment: That's not the way the site works. We don't go somewhere else to get the information needed to understand your question. See [mre] and [ask]. All relevant content must be here in the question itself so that it is available to future site users.

Answer (score 1):

range construct:

```
={A:A, B:B, D:D, G:G;
  A:A, C:C, E:E, F:F}
```

or shorter:

```
={A:B, D:D, G:G;
  A:A, C:C, E:F}
```

use:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(SORT({A:B, D:D, G:G; A:A, C:C, E:F}, 1, ), 
 "select Col3
  where Col4 > 10 
    and Col2 = '"&K1&"'
  limit 10"))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton. Just for my own understanding, when you have the "limit 10" at the end of the query - what makes that query work from the bottom up (or from most recent to most distant?). Is that because I've included a date column? Or does limit 10 just automatically work off the bottom of the spreadsheet upwards? In theory, what change to the code/query would make it query the first 10 instances?

Comment: Also, how would I make the  "where Col4 > 10 " part both > one number and < another number? Let's say I have 10 in Z1 and 25 in Z2. How could I have it query only where Col4 > Z1 and Col4 < Z2?

Comment: @fbnhost1 there is a SORT function right before it goes into the QUERY. to reverse the SORT change `, 1, )` to `, 1, 1)`. `limit 10` is always from top to bottom but that SORT flips the whole dataset so we can cut those 10 instances from the top. for 10 - 25 value range you just add `and Col4 < 25` . if you want it referenced it will be: `where Col4 > "&Z1&" and Col4 < "&Z2&" and Col2........`

Answer (score 0):

I won't calculate the average, just so you can see the data records the query is pulling, and confirm the records.  But I think my formula works.

```
=query(
   query(
     {query(A1:G,"select A,B,D,G where B='"&K1&"' ",0);
      query(A1:G,"select A,C,E,F where C='"&K1&"' ",0)},
     "select * order by Col1 desc limit 10",0),
   "select * where Col4 > 10",0)
```

To get the average, change the last line of the formula to:

`"select avg(Col3) where Col4 > 10",0)`

Note: my understanding is that you want to filter the ten latest records with New York, and then filter those ten records to just those which have a value > 10 in the right column.  This is different then the ten latest records that are New York AND have a value > 10 in the right column.  But either solution can be provided.

I've stacked two queries together, to make the correct columns align vertically.  So the first inner query gets column A,B,D and G, checking for New York (ie equal to K1) in B.  Then the second query stacks columns A,C,E, and F underneath, checking for New York in C.

An outer query then sorts them in descending order by the date column, Col1 (column A).  By setting a limit of ten, we get the ten latest records.

A final query is used to select the records with Col4>10.  By changing this query to just return the avg(Col3), you should have your desired result.

It should be easy to modify this formula to get what you need.

Note also I believe that you missed a couple of records to be blue - G21 and F28?  And E21 should be green also?

### Update

When using the final version of the formula, to extract the Average, you can add the `LABEL` parameter to the `QUERY` statement to rename, or remove, the header label for that average.  So in my example, the `SELECT` statement would become:

```
"select avg(Col3) where Col4 > 10 label avg(Col3) ''   ",0)
```

or

```
"select avg(Col3) where Col4 > 10 label avg(Col3) 'New Label Name Here'   ",0)
```

[image]

### Update #2

I have provided a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AQb7QfuH5aF6DQTVJyGwGSakTaUaZP4y1BYJ30FpLJY/edit?usp=sharing), which has the enhancements you requested.  The formula that calculates the result, the average, is in J3.  The formula looks to a variable cell, I3, for the city name.  I3 uses data validation, from a list in K2:L, to present the drop down  list of city names to pick from.

The selection criteria are located in J6 and J7.  If you had standard values you wanted to pick from here, maybe between 10 and 20, they could also be presented with a drop down list.  But otherwise, just type in the desired limit values.

As an enhancement, I used conditional formatting to color the active cells in the data.  Note that all matching rows will get colored, not just the latest ten.  But the formula calculating the average should just be suing the ten latest, THEN applying the criteria, before calculating the average.  Test this carefully to be sure it is doing what you expect.

Note that the correct placement of the single and double quotes is very important when referencing criteria cells with the `SELECT ... WHERE ...` statements.  Comparison to text values requires single quotes, whereas comparison to numeric values excludes the single quotes.

Valid QUERY Select statements for a numeric comparison:

```
"select * where A >= " & $B$5 & " limit 5 "
```

Valid QUERY Select statements for a text/string comparison:

```
"select * where A >= 'New York' limit 5 "
"select * where A >= '" & $B$5 & "' limit 5 "
```

<<== Do not have any spaces between the single and double quotes!

Invalid QUERY Select statements for a text/string comparison

```
"select * where A >= "New York" limit 5 "
```

<<== Do not have any spaces between the single and double quotes!

```
"select * where A >= ' " & $B$5 & " ' limit 5 "
```

<<== Valid, but matches " New York ", not "New York"!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, and I appreciate you laying it out like that where you posted the initial structure as well. It makes it very easy for me to modify. Yes you are right, I missed a couple of the cells that you noted. Thanks for pointing that out. I do have one followup question - when I do the average query, is there any way to get rid of the "avg" text in the cell above the average output? Or change the text to something custom instead of "avg"?

Comment: Great, thank you. One more quick follow up then if you have the time for it. I've already figured out "select Avg(Col3) where Col4 >"&Z1 ,0) will let me reference the cell Z1 instead of using a fixed value, which before was 10. Is there any way to incorporate that along with the label you just updated in your last reply? I'm confused because of how the quotation marks are set up.

Comment: Oh and one more...would it be possible to do where Col4 > 10 AND < 20? Specifically with the referencing the numbers in other cells (ie Z1 and Z2)?

Comment: Should all be possible.  Will work on it as soon as I can, maybe tomorrow though